# Deleting Users with Rails Console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I want to delete some users and duplicate tags that are in my db. Is there a way I can use rails console to list all of these objects so I can pinpoint each one to delete them. They are not necessarily the last entries?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Assuming your model is derived from `ActiveRecord::Base` and named `User`, you can do
with `rails console`

```
pp User.all  # all users
```

or

```
pp User.all(:conditions => {:firstname => 'fred'}) # use hash conditions
```

or

```
pp User.all(:conditions => "lastname LIKE 'jenkin%'") # use custom sql conditions
```

and having the right user (say, id 42), you can do

```
User.delete(42)
```

That `pp` stands for pretty print. Another sometimes handy is `y` which prints stuff in Yaml format.

Comment: Ok, it was Rails 3 :/ Might not be applicable there with all the fancy ORM changes

Comment: thank you. If you know any more Rails Console cmds & top tips please post them above :-)

Comment: Note that with Rails 4 and above, where should be used instead when using any conditions. So the last two queries would become

`y User.where(firstname: 'fred')` and `y User.where("lastname LIKE 'jenkin%'")`